How to play a video from a web view without it going full screen automatically?
Using react-native-webview, I am rendering a live stream. Currently, when I play any video on the webview, the video automatically opens to full screen and takes over the entire iphone. Is there a way to disable that? Im currently in expo but can eject if needed.
How can I play a video without triggering full screen automatically?
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function LiveStream(props) {
  const {stream, index} = props;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
        source={{
          uri: "https://youtube.com",
        }}
        style={{ flex: 1, width: 320, height: 200,   }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}


You can use the allowsFullscreenVideo prop provided by react-native-webview to disable the automatic fullscreen behavior. By default, this prop is true, allowing videos to go fullscreen. Setting it to false prevents this behavior.
allowsFullscreenVideo={false}: 

This prop disables the fullscreen behavior when a video is played inside the WebView.


import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function LiveStream(props) {
  const { stream, index } = props;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
        source={{
          uri: stream, // Pass the stream URL dynamically
        }}
        style={{ flex: 1, width: 320, height: 200 }}
        allowsFullscreenVideo={false} // Disable fullscreen on video play
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});




Did you test? Doesnt work for me :(
